# Подскажите как правильно реализовать ползунки

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как правильно реализовать ползунки?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StackOverflow не предназначен для просьб "сделайте за меня", поэтому в следующий раз попытайтесь сами, а если не получится, задавайте вопросы.

Ползунки можно реализовать с помощью:

```
 <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50">
```

Пример реализации можете посмотреть [тут](https://html5css.ru/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.php).

Для реакта просто нужно будет хранить значения input в state.